# Rotate more than 360 deg using css 3 matrix

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I am using CSS transitions like this:

```
div
{
   -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
   -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s;
}
div:hover
{
   -webkit-transform: rotate(720deg);
}
```

This effectively makes the div rotate 2 times for 2 seconds. Now I want to use the matrix so that I can rotate and scale the image; however the matrix does not use degrees but cos(a) and sin(a) and as we all know cos(0) = cos(360) = cos(720) etc. So using the matrix I am unable to rotate the image more than 359deg.

So I decided to be clever and with JavaScript I took the matrix from a rotated element (720deg) and it looks like this:

```
-webkit-transform: matrix(1, -0.0000000000000004898587196589413, 0.0000000000000004898587196589413, 1, 0, 0);
```

However using this matrix I am not able to rotate the element - I will later calculate the size and apply that too.

So the question is - how do I rotate an element more than 359deg using css 3 matrix transform?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Matrices in CSS 3 define

> a mathematical mapping from one coordinate system into another

([W3C reference](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-transforms/#transform)),

which implies that 720deg is exactly equivalent to 360deg as you pointed out. So you will not be able to do this directly with a matrix.

However, this syntax should work for your need :

```
div:hover {
    transform: scale(1.5,1.5) rotate(720deg);
    transition: transform 3s;
}
```