# CSS rotate not transitioning properly over 225deg?

Tags: css, rotation, css-transitions, css-transforms, transition

I'm trying to make a css-only hamburger icon made of spans which rotate 405deg to create the close icon. I believe that they're rotating the full 405 since I've been playing around with the numbers and it works perfectly up to 225, but the transitions for anything I've tried over 225 appear to find the quickest route, I suppose. The look like they're just rotating 45deg.

I'd be happy with 225deg, actually, but the final project has some box-shadows that become inverted at 225deg, so it has to be at least one full rotation plus the 45deg.

I thought it might be some quirk with chrome displaying rotations over 360deg or something, but it looks the same when I try it on firefox and safari, and it also does the same weird transition at 315deg. I've also googled to see if anyone else has had this problem, and I haven't seen anyone with similar issues out there. In fact, the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13953572/rotate-more-than-360-deg-using-css-3-matrix) makes it sound like it worked for them.

You can see my code here: https://jsfiddle.net/ys3pheb1/10/

```css
header input { opacity: 0; }

header input + label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 20px;
  width: 30px;

  z-index: 5;
}

header input + label span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin-top: -1px;
  display: block;
  transition: .5s;
  background-color: #000;
}

header input + label span:first-child {
  top: 0;
}

header input + label span:last-child {
  top: 100%;
}

header label:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

header input:checked + label span {
  opacity: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

header input:checked + label span:first-child {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(-405deg); /* HERE IS THE FIRST ROTATE */
  transition: all .7s ease;
}

header input:checked + label span:last-child {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(405deg); /* HERE IS THE SECOND ROTATE */
  transition: all .7s ease;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <input id="burger" type="checkbox">

  <label for="burger">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </label>
</header>
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Oh, I should also mention that this is based on JLNLJN's codepen, which you can find here: https://codepen.io/jlnljn/pen/LkXoBb

I should also mention that the original also has a rotate of 405, which is displaying fine for me.

Comment: Looks fine for me in both Firefox and Chromium.

Comment: @jhpratt Hmm, thanks for that info. I'm wondering if it's just my computer, possibly? I don't even know what in the world would cause that. I dunno if I should screen capture it just to show what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `transform: translate` on the `span` elements was causing a problem with using `transform: rotate` on the same elements for the animation.

Instead of using `translate`, you can position the elements using `position: relative` and `top`.

```css
header input {
  opacity: 0;
}

header input+label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 20px;
  width: 30px;
  z-index: 5;
}

header input+label span {
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  display: block;
  transition: .5s;
  background-color: #000;
  position: relative;
}

header input+label span:first-child {
  top: -6px;
}

header input+label span:last-child {
  top: 6px;
}

header label:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

header input:checked+label span {
  opacity: 0;
}

header input:checked+label span:first-child {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all .7s ease;
  top: 4px;
  transform: rotate(405deg);
}

header input:checked+label span:last-child {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all .7s ease;
  transform: rotate(-405deg);
  top: -4px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <input id="burger" type="checkbox">

  <label for="burger">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </label>
</header>
```

Comment: That is showing up for me, and it's a great fall-back if I can't figure out why it's not working, but I rather like transitions since it automatically animates between the two states. I'd have to create a set of animations to reverse the effect, right?

Comment: @something-something Updated answer, there was an issue with the transform property.

Comment: Ahhh, yeah that's working. Thanks. Didn't know that'd be an issue, thanks again for catching it.